# Why didn't I receive cryptography.hazmat.bindings._padding when installing cryptography with StaSh?

Tags: python-3.x, pythonista

I am using Pythonista for iOS and installed the cryptography package using the latest version of [StaSh](https://github.com/ywangd/stash). It looked like there was an issue during installation but it still seemed to be successful:

```
Extracting archive file ...
Archive extracted.
Running setup file ...
TypeError('expected string or bytes-like object',)
Failed to run setup.py
Fall back to directory guessing ...
Package installed: cryptography
```

However, when I try to import Fertnet from cryptography.fertnet I get a ModuleNotFoundError. Apparently I'm missing cryptography.hazmat.bindings._padding. Does anyone have any idea why I'm not getting that module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cryptography module is partly written in C.
Those parts have to be compiled into shared libraries. The libraries are named `_constant_time`, `_openssl` and `_padding` and they *should* be located in `hazmat/bindings`.

AFAICT PyPI only carries compiled packages for linux, windows and macOS but not for IOS.
So my guess is that `setup.py` fails because it cannot compile those libraries.